# Selecting $k$ items from a set in which there are $n_1$ objects of type a $n_2$ objects of type b and $n_3$ objects of type c.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A box contains $5$ red ball, $5$ blue balls, and $5$ green balls. How many ways are there to select $2$ balls.

The answer is $6$: 2b,1b1r,1b1g,1r1g,2r,2g.

What is the general formula to get the number $6$?

For a small case, it is easy to list the possible ways, but what if the box contains many balls of many colours and different numbers of each colour and we had to select a large number, not $2$.

Answer (score 0):

In your example we must find the number of tuples $\langle x_1,x_2,x_3\rangle$ that satisfy the conditions:

1) $x_1+x_2+x_3=2$

2) the $x_i$ are nonnegative integers

3) the $x_i$ do not exceed $5$.

Fortunately condition 3) is a consequence of the conditions 1) and 2) and we can apply [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). This leads to $\binom{2+2}2=6$ solutions.

So there is a way out if condition 3) plays no part in this. Things become more complicated if we are not that fortunate and for the general case sketched by you there is (as far as I know) no plain general formula.